# mongoose is not able to populate ref id with default value empty object

Tags: node.js, mongodb

My schema is as shown below:

```
const order = new Schema({
    order_status: Number, 
    foodtruck_id: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'foodtruck' },
    customer_id: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'user' },
    items: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'items' }],
    user_type: Boolean,
    order_time: Date,
    order_rating: { type: Number, default: 5.0 },
    order_issue_comments: String,
    order_special_instruction: String,
    order_total: Number,
    order_location: String,
    order_coupon_code: String,
    payment_id: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'payment' },
    order_meta: { type: Schema.Types.Mixed, ref: 'order_sub_info', default: {} }
}, { versionKey: false }, { minimize: false });
```

my query is as shown below:

```
order.find({
        'foodtruck_id': foodtruck_id.trim()
    }).populate('customer_id', {
        '_id': 1,
        'user_name': 1,
        'email_id': 1,
        'ph_no': 1,
        'login_type': 1
    }).populate('items').
    populate('order_meta', 'order_otp').exec((err, orderList) => {
        if (err) res.json({
            status: '500',
            message: err
        });
        else {
            console.log("called");
            res.json({
                status: '200',
                message: 'Order list',
                data: orderList
            });
        }
    });
```

For this query,it is giving me `Cast to ObjectId failed for value at path _id` as `order_meta` has default value **{}**. How to have effective populate query so that It can take care of this testcase?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? If you want to populate, you need ObjectId, not Mixed. Also empty object does not make sense - it is either null/undefined or it is acutal reference.

Comment: on front end I want to have `order_meta` of size 0 in case, if there is no entry but not `null` or `undefined`. To handle this testcase, I have used `Mixed` type

Comment: Well this is something related to the data export from database, therefore you should not put this logic into model.

You can rewrite toJSON method, where you can use "if" null then set it as empty object, then it will be serialized this way after you send it to frontend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not good idea to put empty object in a place, where reference id is expected. Both - for having problem with populate and for common sense too (if it is field which has reference, it should be null/undefined or reference itself).

It is common that you want to transform your data at some endpoint, but it should not interfere with database or business logic of application.

You can defined toJSON method that should be used for your model. In your case

```
const order = new Schema({
    order_status: Number, 
    foodtruck_id: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'foodtruck' },
    customer_id: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'user' },
    items: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'items' }],
    user_type: Boolean,
    order_time: Date,
    order_rating: { type: Number, default: 5.0 },
    order_issue_comments: String,
    order_special_instruction: String,
    order_total: Number,
    order_location: String,
    order_coupon_code: String,
    payment_id: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'payment' },
    order_meta: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'order_sub_info'}
}, { versionKey: false }, { minimize: false });

order.options.toJSON = {
        transform(zipRequestDocument, ret, options) { // eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars
            if (!ret.order_meta){
                 ret.order_meta = {};
            }
        },
    };
```